# Interesting Program behaviour for Project Euler p21

Tags: java, python, algorithm

I have got a solution for problem 21 in python and it gives the right answer. I tried out someone else's java code and I get the same answer for a value of 10000 and 100000 but when 1000000 is tried, the solution returned by my code differs from two other solutions returned by java code even though all three solutions returned are same for tested values of 10000 and 1000000 and 50000. Anyone got any ideas?

My Python code

```
def amicable_pairs(n):
    """returns sum of all amicable pairs under n. See project euler for 
    definition of an amicable pair"""
    div_sum = [0]*n
    amicable_pairs_set = [0]*n
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(i*2, n, i):
            div_sum[j] += i
    #for i in range(1, n):
     #   div_sum[i] = sum([j + i/j for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(i)) + 1) if i % j == 0 and i != i/j])
      #  div_sum[i] = div_sum[i] + 1

    #print div_sum
    for j in range(n):
        if div_sum[j] < n and div_sum[div_sum[j]] == j and div_sum[j] != j:
            amicable_pairs_set[j] = j
            amicable_pairs_set[div_sum[j]] = div_sum[j]
    return sum(amicable_pairs_set)
```

Java code 1:

```
public class AmicableNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long strTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int sum_ami = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < 1000000; j++) {
            int ad = sum_devisors(j);
            if (((sum_devisors(ad)) == j) && (j != ad)) {
                sum_ami += j;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum_ami);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("time is " + (endTime - strTime) + " ms");
    }

    public static int sum_devisors(int number) {
        if ((number == 1) || (number == 2)) {
            return 1;
        }
        int sum = 0;
        int k = (int) Math.sqrt(number);
        for (int i = 2; i < k; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                sum += i;
                sum += (number / i);
            }
        }
        if (k * k == number) {
            sum += k;
        }
        return (sum + 1);// every number divided by 1
    }
}
```

Java code 2:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AmicableNumbers {

    /**
     * @author Pavan Koppolu
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //scan the input
        System.out.println("Enter a number, to find out sum of amicable numbers: ");
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int input=scan.nextInt();
        long before=System.currentTimeMillis();
        // getting the result
        long result=sumOfAllAmicableNumbersUptoGivenNumber(input);
        long after=System.currentTimeMillis();
        // prints the result on the console
        System.out.println("Sum of all amicable numbers below "+input+" : "+result+" Elasped Time : "+(after-before)+" ms");
    }
    /*
     * calculate the sum of the amicable numbers upto the given number
     */
    private static long sumOfAllAmicableNumbersUptoGivenNumber(int input)
    {
        long sum=0,factorsSum=0,sumOfFactors=0; 
        for(long j=2;j<input;j++)
        {
            factorsSum=getFactorsSum(j);
            if(j!=factorsSum)
            {
                sumOfFactors=getFactorsSum(factorsSum);
                if(j==sumOfFactors)
                    sum+=j;
            }   
            else
                continue;
        }       
        return sum;
    }
    /*
     * find out the sum of the factors
     */
    private static long getFactorsSum(long j)
    {
        long sum=1;
        for(int k=2;k<=Math.sqrt(j);k++)
        {
            if(j%k==0)
                sum+=k+j/k;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

In fact the solutions returned by all three above differ from each other for an input of 1000000

Comment: is your system 16 bit? is int 16 bit in your machine?

Comment: My system is a 64ibt Mac OSX.

Comment: do the returned values differ very small?

Comment: python returns a value of 25275024, java code 1 returns a value of 26464963 while java code 2 returns a value of 27220963

Comment: in last java code, input is int, all others are long. can you make that int to long and try again? or can you make all longs to int

Comment: did you try changing     if (k * k == number) to                        if ((k * k) == number) {

Comment: all that doesnt make any difference

Comment: for (int i = 2; i < k; i++) { in second code differs                 from for(int k=2;k<=Math.sqrt(j);k++) of the last code < and <=

Comment: if you try 1000001 for the second code, will it be same for 1000000 with last code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13914/discussion-between-cobie-and-tugrul-buyukisik)

Comment: I think it can be taken as a given that some intermediate results don't fit into 31, respectively 63 bits. Try using BigInteger instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is that there are amicable pairs where one partner is less than 1 million and the other is larger than 1 million, namely

```
(947835,1125765), (998104,1043096)
```

The Python code doesn't count them,

```
for j in range(n):
    if div_sum[j] < n and div_sum[div_sum[j]] == j and div_sum[j] != j:
```

but the Java code counts the smaller members of these pairs. That explains the output of the second Java code, since

```
25275024 + 947835 + 998104 == 27220963
```

The output of the first Java code is smaller because it omits the amicable pair

```
(356408, 399592)
```

The reason is that

```
356408 = 596*598
```

but in the code there is

```
int k = (int) Math.sqrt(number);
for (int i = 2; i < k; i++) {
```

thus the divisor sum is miscalculated for all numbers divisible by `floor(sqrt(n))` that are not squares (Note that the second Java code miscalculates the divisor sum for all squares).

Comment: Just discovered this. Would you call the java code adding the amicable pair with one of pair over a million a bug in the code?

Comment: That depends on the specification of the problem. With the wording of the PE problem, I'd say adding the smaller member of the pair crossing the threshold is the correct way.